# sc_serv Shoutcast stream plays intro file, but does not play stream

Tags: shoutcast, internet-radio

Shoutcast docs say I can set an intro file to play when client connects with the following in sc_serv.conf file:

```
IntroFile=hawkad%d.mp3
```

When the client connects (ie VLC), it successfully plays the intro audio file, but doesn't stream the source from the broadcasting client after that. There are no errors in sc_serv.log file to indicate an issue, so I am uncertain what is causing the issue.

The introfile is a 128k bitrate file, named hawkad128.mp3

Any assistance is greatly appreciated getting this to work.

snip of sc_serv.log

```
2023-01-20 10:45:53 DEBUG   ident is DIDC7cbfe1e5ac534c819760f0f27fe02820-8000, DID is e7ccb8b69a8c41d99e9d91422834ddf663499bdf7762f3dde7a2e7f416427e6
2023-01-20 10:45:53 INFO    [MAIN] Starting 2 network threads
2023-01-20 10:45:53 INFO    [RIP] Reserved 14 IP's from global rip file
2023-01-20 10:45:53 INFO    [MICROSERVER] Listening for source and client connections on port 8000
2023-01-20 10:45:53 INFO    [MICROSERVER] Listening for legacy source connections on port 8001
2023-01-20 10:45:53 INFO    [MICROSERVER] Flash policy file server not enabled
2023-01-20 10:45:57 INFO    [SRC 74.123.47.237:41970 sid=3] SHOUTcast 1 source connection starting.
2023-01-20 10:45:57 INFO    [SRC 74.123.47.237:41970 sid=3] Loaded intro file `hawkad128.mp3' (68758 bytes - processed down to 68545 bytes)
2023-01-20 10:45:57 INFO    [SRC 74.123.47.237:41972 sid=1] SHOUTcast 1 source connection starting.
2023-01-20 10:45:57 INFO    [SRC 74.123.47.237:41972 sid=1] Loaded intro file `hawkad128.mp3' (68758 bytes - processed down to 68545 bytes)
2023-01-20 10:46:09 INFO    [DST 74.123.47.237:49388 sid=1] HTTP client connection accepted. User-Agent: `VLC/3.0.18 LibVLC/3.0.18', UID: 1, GRID: 1
2023-01-20 10:46:09 INFO    [DST 74.123.47.237:49388 sid=1] HTTP client connection closed (0 seconds) [Bytes: 7940] Agent: `VLC/3.0.18 LibVLC/3.0.18', UID: 1, GRID: 1
2023-01-20 10:46:09 INFO    [DST 74.123.47.237:49389 sid=1] SHOUTcast 1 client connection accepted. User-Agent: `VLC/3.0.18 LibVLC/3.0.18', UID: 2, GRID: 2
2023-01-20 10:46:11 INFO    [DST 88.99.58.163:49840 sid=1] SHOUTcast 1 client connection accepted. User-Agent: `WinampMPEG/5.50', UID: 3, GRID: 3
2023-01-20 10:46:19 INFO    [ADMINCGI sid=1] Title updated [Volbeat - Don’t Tread on Me]
2023-01-20 10:46:19 INFO    [YP sid=1] Stream #1 has been updated on the SHOUTcast Directory.
2023-01-20 10:46:24 INFO    [ADMINCGI sid=3] Title updated [Craig Padilla - Perspective of Disappearance ~ , Zero Ohms, Skip Murphy]
2023-01-20 10:46:24 INFO    [YP sid=3] Stream #3 has been updated on the SHOUTcast Directory.
```

This is the sc_serv.conf file

```
;======================================================
; Hawkwynd Radio sc_serv configuration file
; last updated 1/20/23 
; =====================================================

publicserver=always
adminpassword=redacted
password=redacted
requirestreamconfigs=1
streamautodumptime_1=180
autodumptime_1=180

; stream_1 configuration

streamadminpassword_1=redacted
streamid_1=1
streampassword_1=redacted
;serverport_1=8000
streampath_1=stream
streamauthhash_1=FDC1C391-A44D-47B5-840A-00C34DA9AA38

; Intro File 
IntroFile="hawkad%d.mp3"
   
; stream_2 configuration

streamid_2=2
streampassword_2=redacted
; streamport_2=8000
streampath_2=test

; ambient stream configuration
streamid_3=3
streampassword_3=redacted
streampath_3=ambient 

; general configuration

logfile=logs/sc_serv.log
w3clog=logs/sc_w3c.log
banfile=control/sc_serv.ban
ripfile=control/sc_serv.rip

shoutcast1clientdebug=0
shoutcast2clientdebug=0
httpclientdebug=0
shoutcastsourcedebug=0
uvox2sourcedebug=0
httpsourcedebug=0
relayshoutcastdebug=0
relayuvoxdebug=0
relaydebug=0
httpstyledebug=0
webclientdebug=0
admetricsdebug=0
yp2debug=0
streamdatadebug=0
statsdebug=0
microserverdebug=0
threadrunnerdebug=0
forceshortsends=1
ratelimit=0
flvclientdebug=0
W3CEnable=Yes
streamauthhash_2=2CFE193B-7B42-416C-A4B7-5F86BEEE0C6F
streamauthhash_3=5ad7056f-82e3-4417-8813-94b23acff819
```

I used the following command to convert the mp3 file to 128k bitrate

```
ffmpeg -v debug -i "hawkad1.mp3" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn "hawkad128.mp3"
```

Comment: The stream works without the intro file?  I wonder if there's something weird about the intro file that's causing issues.  You don't have any ID3 tags or anything in it, right?  Can you post the file so we can see it?

Comment: The stream works fine without it the introFile= commented out. When active, the intro file plays, but after it finishes, (just a :03 second file) the source stream does not play. Which file are you referring to? The intro file?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the sc_serv.conf file (passwords redacted)

Comment: Removed the ID3 tags from the mp3 file with no success. BTW, the source is a liquidsoap generated stream from my local machine to the ec2 instance running sc_serv. If that makes any difference.

Comment: Does the MP3 have the same sample rate and channel count as the stream?  Can you post a link to your stream?

Comment: http://hawkwynd.com:8000/listen.pls?sid=1 -- vlc and other clients

Comment: I'm not having any trouble with your stream in VLC or in a browser.  Do you have the intro file running right now?

Comment: No, it is disabled currently. If you're listening now, I will enable it and you can re-connect.

Comment: Input #0, mp3, from 'hawkad_nometa_128.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.26, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavf
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - -7.000000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown,

Comment: Input #0, mp3, from 'http://hawkwynd.com:8000/stream':
  Metadata:
    icy-br          : 128
    icy-sr          : 44100
    icy-url         : http://stream.hawkwynd.com
    icy-pub         : 1
    StreamTitle     : The Moody Blues - Your Wildest Dreams
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s

Comment: It's matching the bitrate and frequency in Hz, so I am at a loss why the stream does not play after the intro file plays. I'm going to enable the sc_serv debug and see if it spits out something like an error or warning.

Comment: Alright, well, I was going to test and poke at the bitstream with a hex editor to see what was weird.  Just turn it on and do a packet capture of the first megabyte or something if you don't want to leave the intro file on.

Comment: The server just flushes the contents of your file to the client, and then picks up with the stream right after.  (At least, it did in earlier SHOUTcast versions... I haven't messed with it lately.)  So whatever the problem is has to do with the re-sync between the intro file and the stream.  These intro files have always been a bit problematic, but usually the client rolls with it.

Comment: I will try using a different into file. Thank you for your assistance.